# How to detect when a windows get a WM_MOVE message

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Im trying to detect when a remote process receive a WM_MOVE message so I can 
re-scan the new window position and change my window accordingly
(Im creating a overlay)

I think I might need to use a DLL injection but the Microsoft documentation is so horrible and incoherent that I can't figure out the bare minimum required to perform the injection and just know when a WM_MOVE message was sent to the remote process

Comment: Please more accurately describe your problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Don't fiddle with internal implementation details. Use the standard infrastructure instead, namely [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx), monitoring [EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) events.

Comment: What do you mean by `remote process`?

Comment: The process for wich im trying to "spy" on the messages is not a child process a.k.a I don't have the owning right over the process however I have access administrative rights

Comment: A parent process does not have any particular rights over a process it spawns. It sounds like you have experience with some other OS and presume, that any other OS would be like the one you are familiar with. I don't know which OS you are familiar with, but rights management works differently in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For low-level support, use SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CALLWNDPROC or WH_CALLWNDPROCRET. On x64 Windows you will need to write a 32-bit dll, a 64-bit dll, and have both a 32-bit process and 64-bit process call it with each respective dll (because a 32-bit process can't set a 64-bit hook and vice-versa). Then you write an IPC mechanism from your injected dll to your main process, if necessary. But be sure to make it efficient wrt CPU usage! If "Show window contents while dragging" is enabled, there will be many WM_MOVE messages during a window move.

For higher-level support, use SetWinEventHook with EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE and make sure that you are only processing it for top-level windows.

The latter is usually preferred over the former, because it is more reliable.